# PHP insert data into Apache log

Tags: php, apache

I'm wanting to switch to mpm_event to be able to serve a higher rate of requests.  The server is basically just serving files, but there is a php application running on the server. I've been using prefork up until now. The php application uses the apache_note() function to insert some information into the apache log, but apache_note() isn't compatible when you aren't running php as an apache process. Is there another method to do this other than apache_note() ?